# How do I proceed with creating a panel which can search a page in wicket and redirect to the same

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6, wicketstuff

I am trying to do the following:

I already have a menu with several drop downs in wicket right now. However the number of entries have become very large in the drop downs, one has to remember headers under which a particular page exists. I would like to create a landing page, which would have a search bar in which we can type in the page name and I should be redirected to the desired page.

Can anybody give me any pointers of how to proceed with this one? Thanks!

Comment: I think, that this is not a good approach to make users typein page name somewhere to obtain this page (there is browser url promt to achive this ). Maybe better use trees or submenus and reduce pages number. I think, some pages can be merged into one page, which can receive page parameters and show information according to them. Do you really need what you described in question?

Comment: @MichaelZhavzharov thank you for tour comment. Yes I would need to do this, there are some other apps in my company that already do that but they are not built on top of wicket. Thanks!

Comment: ok. Then, you can take input string from TextField (via PropertyModel, for example), call method with switch-case construction relative to this inputted string, which will return .class for requested page (or home page, if string does not suit any page), and call setResponsePage( fetchedClass ) method. Or you want something more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use AutoCompleteTextField to show user the available pages. Then, after user has selected a page, you can redirect him/her to the page.